# get output audio from computer (using c#)

Tags: c#

I've been researching this for ages and nothing seems to work for me. I'm using Visual c# and I'm pretty much a beginner. I've been trying to capture the loudness of music playing on the computer while its playing, and put it in some variable I can use in my program.

I know there are lots of questions about this, but none of them have worked for me. The Naudio website isn't helping, and the stuff on the Microsoft website seems to be all in C++?!?

Comment: you can still call the win32 api using c#

Answer (score 0):

For a windows OS up until Windows XP, you could use pinvoke to get the sound level:

```
    // Pre Windows Vista
    [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
    public static extern int waveOutGetVolume(IntPtr hwo, out uint dwVolume);
```

From win vista and up, this part got redesigned and wrapped in [the Core Sound API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370802%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You might want to take a look at the http://naudio.codeplex.com/ library. They have wrappers for 
getting the master volume.

```
    MMDeviceEnumerator DevEnum = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
    MMDevice device = DevEnum.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia);
    int result = (int)(device.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevelScalar * 100);
```

Comment: First create the variable with `uint volume;`, then fill it with `waveOutGetVolume(IntPtr.Zero, out volume);`.

Comment: Sorry this only seems to get the volume setting, not the output loudness.